# Is there a way to convert all the uploaded PNG images to JPEG?

Tags: media

Is there a way to convert all the uploaded PNG images in a Drupal 7 site to JPEG?

Manually doing it would require much time. Therefore, I'm looking for an automatic way to convert them.

Comment: The simplest way would be to set up a CLI script to convert them using [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).  If you need help with CLI scripting, try StackOverflow.

Comment: Drupal Core ImageCache can process images on the fly. There are lots of contrib modules available for it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With imagecache_actions module you have several actions. One of then is "File Format switcher" so you can serve JPEG instead of png without converting the source images.

For more information:
https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions